# How to display the Facebook profile photo in my php project

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my project I am signing in with a Facebook account, but the profile page displays the image from gravatar.com. I want to display the profile image from www.facebook.com of registered users.
In my local system I have the following code to display profile photo from www.gravatar.com

```
public function gravatar($email, $s = 80, $d = 'mm', $r = 'g', $img = FALSE, $atts = array())
{
    $url = 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/'
        . md5(strtolower(trim( $email)))
        . "?s=$s&d=$d&r=$r";

    if ($img)
    {
        $url = '<img src="' . $url . '"';
        foreach ($atts as $key => $val)
        {
            $url .= ' ' . $key . '="' . $val . '"';
        }
        $url .= ' />';
    }
    return $url;
}
```

How can I display the Facebook profile photo instead of gravatar.com profile photo?

Comment: Your code doesn't explain how your fb users differ from others

Answer (score 1):

You can link to `https://graph.facebook.com/usernameOrId/picture`.

Comment: Can u please explain in detail if you feel free.because i am new to this technolozy.........

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
function facebookAvatar($uid, $img = FALSE, $atts = array())
{
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.trim($uid).'/picture';

    if ($img)
    {   
        $url = '<img src="' . $url . '"';
        foreach ($atts as $key => $val)
        {
            $url .= ' ' . $key . '="' . $val . '"';
        }
        $url .= ' />';
    }
    return $url;
}
```

and to get the Image use:

```
<?php echo facebookAvatar('UsernameOrUserID', TRUE, array('width'=>'80px', 'height'=>'80px')); ?>
```

UsernameOrUserID you've to change to the UserID:

**1234321**

if the url is:

http://facebook.com/profile.php?id=**1234321**

or to the username:

**my.name**

if the facebook url is http://facebook.com/**my.name**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP SDK you can get the userId of the current logged in USer and display the user Image.

You can do like this:

```
require_once 'path/to/facebookSDK.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
       'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
       'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

//this will ouptput your current logged in user facebook image
echo getFacebookPhotoAvatar ($user);

function getFacebookPhotoAvatar ($user) {
      if($user) {
            $photoUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$user."/picture";
            $facebookPhoto = '<img src="'.$photoUrl.'" alt="FacebookUserImage"/>';
      } else {
            $facebookPhoto = '';
      }

      return $facebookPhoto ;
}
```

Hope this helps :)